# Transmittance through a reversed one-way mirror

Tags: optics

I am looking to use a half silvered one-way mirror to allow as much light and solar energy as possible into a room where there are highly reflective surfaces within the room - and I want to keep the energy from reflecting back outside - trap as much light/energy as I can in the room. That's why I am wondering what percentage of sun-light would be transmitted through a "reversed" one-way mirror with the clear glass side of the mirror to the outside and the half-silvered side on the surface inside the room? And to what extent might this arrangement reflect solar light/energy back into the room?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509129/2451

Comment: You can't really trap light, it is better to absorb it.  50% of whatever hits either side will transmit.  Better to have no window and black surfaces in the room.

Answer (score 1):

There is [no such thing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101380/how-does-a-one-sided-glass-work/101387#101387) as a [one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/498482/optical-systems-that-make-a-ray-of-light-travel-a-different-way-to-and-from/)-[way](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162678/is-there-something-equivalent-to-a-diode-for-light/) [mirror](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179171/can-a-one-way-mirror-effect-be-reversed).

If you want a mirror to reflect 99% of the light that tries to get out of the cavity, then that mirror will also need to reject 99% of the light that tries to get in.